# addTarget to UIButton programmatically gives me 'unrecognized selector sent to class'

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to learn how to create button target actions, however, when I press the button, I get those LLDB errors and I get told that it was an 'unrecognized selector sent to class'.

Where am I going wrong here?

StatusCell.swift:

```
let phoneIcon: UIButton = {
        let iv = UIImageView()

        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "Phone3")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

        let phoneBtn = UIButton(type: .Custom)

        phoneBtn.addTarget(CallButton.self, action: #selector(CallButton.buttonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        phoneBtn.addTarget(CallButton.self, action: #selector(CallButton.buttonReleased(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        phoneBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        phoneBtn.setImage(iv.image!, forState: .Normal)
        phoneBtn.tintColor = UIColor(r: 224, g: 224, b: 224)

        return phoneBtn

    }()
```

Here's the CallButton class where I call for buttonPressed and buttonReleased.

```
class CallButton: UIControl {

    func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject?) {
        print("Pressed")
    }
    func buttonReleased(sender: AnyObject?) {
        print("Let go")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the *class itself*, **not** an instance, as the target of the action.

Therefore, the method you set as the action should be implemented as a class method, *not* an instance method:

```
class func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject?) {
    print("Pressed")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for parameter `target` must be an instance of `CallButton`, not the type itself.